# VSS Client SDK doc link is unavailable - https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

VSS Client SDK doc link is unavailable - https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk

Anyone knows where the new one is?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/azuredevops/comments/i0zs3s/vss_sdk_api_docs/).

majority of the Azure DevOps web UI has been converted to new React-based components.

> The new [Azure DevOps extension sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample) uses a new [Azure DevOps
> SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk) along with the React-based components in the Azure DevOps UI
> library. A full API reference of can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-sdk/)

.

Comment: Thanks man. (MS also replied me the same :).

Anyway, the Azure extension development documentation overall is hard to follow and understand...


I mean they should handle their 404 pages more elegantly and dev-friendly at least. And the tutorials are kind of too brief...

Comment: I am also working at MS

Comment: Good to know, lol